# Making active nav links

Tags: jquery, css

Can someone tell me why my links don't stay active when I go from one category to another? What should I include more ? I have also included the jQuery library.

This is my css:

```
.themesButton
{

  background-color:transparent;
  border:1px solid #61BD6D;
  display:inline-block;
  cursor:pointer;
  color:#61BD6D;
  font-family:Arial;
  font-size:12px;
  padding:8px 30px;
  text-decoration:none;
  width: 178px;
  height: 35px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}


.themesButton .active
{

  background-color:transparent;
  border:1px solid #61BD6D;
  display:inline-block;
  cursor:pointer;
  color:#61BD6D;
  font-family:Arial;
  font-size:12px;
  padding:8px 30px;
  text-decoration:none;
  width: 178px;
  height: 35px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

These are my links:

```
<a href="/dizainu-parduotuve/" style="text-decoration: none;" class="themesButton">Visi dizainai</a>
    <a href="/dizainai/kategorija/asmenines-svetaines" style="text-decoration: none;" class="themesButton">Asmeninės</a>
    <a href="/dizainai/kategorija/parduotuviu-dizainai" style="text-decoration: none;" class="themesButton">Parduotuvių dizainai</a>
    <a href="/dizainai/kategorija/zaidimu-dizainai" style="text-decoration: none;" class="themesButton">Žaidimų dizainai</a>
    <a href="/dizainai/kategorija/ivairus-dizainai" style="text-decoration: none;" class="themesButton">Įvairus dizainai</a>
```

This is my function:

```
     <script>
        $(function() {
             var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href
        .lastIndexOf("/")+1);
             $(".themesButton").each(function(){
                  if($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == '' )
                  $(this).addClass("active");
             })
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what action takes place when you say you go from one category to another?

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS you have `.themesButton .active`. This is looking for children of `.themesButton` with class `active` not elements which have both classes. If you remove the space between the classes it will look for elements which have both classes. i.e. `.themesButton.active`

Also, both of your declarations have the same properties so you won't be able to tell the difference when one is active.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mg5dyc6z/1/)